# "Missing right parenthesis" error - Oracle

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

When I create this code:

```
SQL> create table TRANSAKSI_9223(
  2  ID_Transaksi number(13)
  3  constraint idtransaksi_pk primary key,
  4  Tgl_Transaksi date constraint tgl_notnull not null,
  5  Total_harga float,
  6  id_pembeli number(13), constraint fk_idpembeli references PEMBELI_9223(id_pembeli));
id_pembeli number(13), constraint fk_idpembeli references PEMBELI_9223(id_pembeli))
                                                                      *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are those line numbers really part of your code? If so remove them, if not clean up your code in the question

Comment: May be you can try this. `create table TRANSAKSI_9223(
    ID_Transaksi number(13)
    constraint idtransaksi_pk primary key,
    Tgl_Transaksi date constraint tgl_notnull not null,
    Total_harga float,
    id_pembeli number(13) constraint fk_idpembeli references PEMBELI_9223(id_pembeli));`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the column name

```
    CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (columnename)
    REFERENCES  PEMBELI_9223(id_pembeli);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you have to repeat the FK column with the `constraint ...` syntax at the end. You can omit it, when you declare the FK constraint inline:

```
create table TRANSAKSI_9223(
  ID_Transaksi number(13)
  constraint idtransaksi_pk primary key,
  Tgl_Transaksi date constraint tgl_notnull not null,
  Total_harga float,
  id_pembeli number(13) references PEMBELI_9223
);
```

note the missing `,` after the column definition. You can also omit the target column with that syntax. It will automatically use the PK column of the target table.

You can include the constraint name as well:

```
create table TRANSAKSI_9223(
  ID_Transaksi number(13)
  constraint idtransaksi_pk primary key,
  Tgl_Transaksi date constraint tgl_notnull not null,
  id_pembeli number(13) constraint fk_idpembeli references PEMBELI_9223,
  Total_harga float
);
```

Again, no `,` after the column definition. I moved the column to a different position, to make it more obvious that this is part of the column definition not a constraint at the end of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE transaksi_9223
(
   id_transaksi   NUMBER (13) CONSTRAINT idtransaksi_pk PRIMARY KEY,
   tgl_transaksi  DATE CONSTRAINT tgl_notnull NOT NULL,
   total_harga    FLOAT,
   id_pembeli     NUMBER (13)
                     CONSTRAINT fk_idpembeli
                         REFERENCES pembeli_9223 (id_pembeli)
);
```

I.e. remove comma, here:

```
  id_pembeli number(13), constraint fk_idpembeli
                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to say which column is the foreign key (I am guessing id_pembeli)

```
constraint fk_idpembeli  FOREIGN KEY (id_pembeli) references PEMBELI_9223(id_pembeli)
```